# Disable to create folders for every years and months in uploads folder

Tags: directory, uploads

How can I disable to create folders for every years and months in uploads folder?

I mean there is a lot of folder under "wp-content/uploads", and the majority of them are empty. Why create WP these folders?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens because of the option selected in Settings-> Media (Organinze media into folders), you can disable it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this by going to **Settings -> Media**

[image: Media Settings]

If you uncheck the setting all the **future** media uploads will directly into `wp-content/uploads` folder.

> Why create WP these folders?

WP doesn't create empty folders, I assume those folders are created when you have uploaded media and now they they are empty because you might have mass deleted media files for those months. WP doesn't delete folder once there are no media files(I mean once you have deleted all corresponding media files).

---

My opinion is that it's not a big deal that even if we have empty folders.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @bravokeyl's answer, the reason to the creation of those empty directories is a minor bug in wordpress code that prepares a folder to which it will be able to upload files into, at an API which is not always used as part of the upload process. But except for being annoying to the eye, those empty folders do not have any impact on performance or anything else

Answer (score 1):

## *Au contraire, mon capitain!*

Both *nix and Windoze count all files and directories as inodes.  The more inodes: the slower directory reading/access, regardless.  This is why some hosts will limit the quantity of inodes.  It may be insignificant depending on your specific configuration, but it impacts access speeds nonetheless.

See:

#### *Will a large number of used inodes cause a server to run slowly*

https://serverfault.com/questions/735435/will-a-large-number-of-used-inodes-cause-a-server-to-run-slowly

and:

#### *How to Free Inode Usage?*

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage%22)

Answer #2:

> Empty directories also consume inodes. Deleting them can free up some inodes. The number can be significant in some use-cases. You can delete empty directories with: find . -type d -empty -delete – Ruchit Patel; Jun 22, 2018 at 9:02"

WordPress should NOT, by default, create directories until they are needed, regardless of requesting origin (API, plugin,theme,  media upload, etc.); its a complete waste of resources, but you cannot tell the WP devs at Automattttic anything, IMHO, but I guess that's their prerogative.

Think of the directory structure as exactly what it is:  a directory, or table of contents, if you will.  The more entries it has (the longer it is). the more time that it takes to read.  Its axiomatic!

I run over a hundred websites, most of which are decades old, with tens of thousands of posts and images in each, so this does effect my instant situation.